# Data still stale after mutation and query invalidation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-query

Expo, React Native: Data still stale after mutation and query invalidation.

Situation: I mutate data displayed on the current screen and then invalidate queries in the 'onSettled' or the 'onSuccess' section.
Problem: Stale data still displayed on the current screen, unless i navigate away from the page and come back.

```
  const { data, isLoading, isError, refetch } = useQuery(
    'getAllCategories',
    getAllCategories,
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setSearchResults(Object.values(data));
      },
    }
  );
  const deleteCategoryMutation = useMutation(
    (id) => {
      deleteCategory({ categoryID: id, saveItems: true });
    },
    {
      onSettled: async () => {
        await queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getAllCategories']);
        refetch();
      },
    }
  );
```